# How to remove text from an input box and send new text using Python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to delete "Apple" and enter "Google", and then click the "Search" button.
This is the url: https://www.glassdoor.ca/Reviews/apple-reviews-SRCH_KE0,5.htm

[image]

The company input box tag:
[image: Company Input Box]

The search button tag:
[image: Search Button]

I'm using the following code:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="sc.keyword"]')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
element.send_keys("Google")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```

But nothing happens. Does anyone know why?  Thank you very much!

[NEW] I just found that if I skip the sign-in step, then the code is able to change the company name.

[LATEST DEVELOPMENT] When I added a line of code to click the "Search" button after sign-in, it works. Thank you, everyone.

The full code is as follows:

```
def open_default_page(target_folder):
    default_url = r"https://www.glassdoor.ca/Reviews/apple-reviews-SRCH_KE0,5.htm"
    browser.implicitly_wait(20)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(default_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    return browser

    
def enter_company(com_name):
# Enter the keyword:

    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Company 
              Name']")

    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    element.send_keys(com_name)

    time.sleep(1)
    # click Search
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)


def sign_in(browser):
    some code
    return browser

# Open the default page
target_folder = r"D:\somefolder"
browser = open_default_page(target_folder)
browser = sign_in(browser)


def main():
    sign_in(target_folder)
    enter_company("Google")
    # followed by some other further steps

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: may be try `.send_keys("")`

Comment: Doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `element.clear()`. Here is the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.clear)

Comment: Can you try this out ?
Wait for the element to be clickable, click on it and then try to clear the text.
```element = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.Xpath, //input[@id="sc.keyword"])))
element.click()
element.clear()```

Comment: Following your code, got the following error message: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: I printed the status before "click", and find that the element is visible: print("Element is visible? " + str(element.is_displayed()))

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment on your post so putting my suggestions here.

Just tried your example "as-is" and it worked well without any changes. Just used Chrome:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.glassdoor.ca/Reviews/apple-reviews-SRCH_KE0,5.htm')
```

Comment: @VictorWang the most likely script failed with some exception. Could you please share all the execution output?

Comment: Probably because of the way I packaged some of the codes into a function. When I put all the codes outside of a function. They are working fine.

Comment: Each part works fine. When I put them together into a function. No error message but the company name is not changed.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue lies in the sign-in step. After sign-in, I clicked the "Search" button to refresh the page and it's fine. I first load a default as an easy alternative to setting the default search type, i.e. companies.